# Validation losses increasing after a few epochs

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm building a small CNN model to predict plant crop disease with the Plant Village Dataset. It consists of 39 classes of different species with and without diseases.

**CNN model**

```
class CropDetectCNN(nn.Module):
    # initialize the class and the parameters
    def __init__(self):
        super(CropDetectCNN, self).__init__()

        # convolutional layer 1 & max pool layer 1
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=3),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2))

        # convolutional layer 2 & max pool layer 2
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2))

        #Fully connected layer
        self.fc = nn.Linear(32*28*28, 39)
        
        

    # Feed forward the network
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out


model = CropDetectCNN()
```

**Training**

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()  # this include softmax + cross entropy loss
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())

def batch_gd(model, criterion, train_loader, validation_loader, epochs):
    train_losses = np.zeros(epochs)
    test_losses = np.zeros(epochs)
    validation_losses = np.zeros(epochs)
    
    for e in range(epochs):
        t0 = datetime.now()
        train_loss = []
        model.train()
        for inputs, targets in train_loader:
            inputs, targets = inputs.to(device), targets.to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            output = model(inputs)

            loss = criterion(output, targets)

            train_loss.append(loss.item())  # torch to numpy world

            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            
        
        train_loss = np.mean(train_loss)

        validation_loss = []

        for inputs, targets in validation_loader:
            
            model.eval()

            inputs, targets = inputs.to(device), targets.to(device)

            output = model(inputs)

            loss = criterion(output, targets)

            validation_loss.append(loss.item())  # torch to numpy world
        
        
        
        validation_loss = np.mean(validation_loss)

        train_losses[e] = train_loss
        validation_losses[e] = validation_loss

        dt = datetime.now() - t0

        print(
            f"Epoch : {e+1}/{epochs} Train_loss: {train_loss:.3f} Validation_loss: {validation_loss:.3f} Duration: {dt}"
        )

    return train_losses, validation_losses

# Running the function
train_losses, validation_losses = batch_gd(
    model, criterion, train_loader, validation_loader, 5
)

# And theses are results:
Epoch : 1/5 Train_loss: 1.164 Validation_loss: 0.861 Duration: 0:10:59.968168
Epoch : 2/5 Train_loss: 0.515 Validation_loss: 0.816 Duration: 0:10:49.199842
Epoch : 3/5 Train_loss: 0.241 Validation_loss: 1.007 Duration: 0:09:56.334155
Epoch : 4/5 Train_loss: 0.156 Validation_loss: 1.147 Duration: 0:10:12.625819
Epoch : 5/5 Train_loss: 0.135 Validation_loss: 1.603 Duration: 0:09:56.746308
```

Isn't the validation loss suppose to decrease with epochs ? So why is it first decreasing and then increasing ?

How should I set the number of epochs, and why ?

Any help is really appreciated !

Comment: it seems like you have several questions within this single post - please ask each question in a different _concise_ post. feel free to link the questions for context

Comment: Ok I'll try to correct that, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are facing the phenomenon of "overfitting" when your validation loss goes up after decreasing. You should stop training at that point and try to use some tricks to avoid overfitting.

Getting different predictions might happen when your gradients keep updating during inference so [try explicitly "stop" them from updating](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/tuning_guide.html#disable-gradient-calculation-for-validation-or-inference) with torch.no_grad()

Comment: Ok yes I understand. So I have to reduce the number of epochs to 2, because it starts to increasing after ?
Concerning predictions, adding a `with torch.no_grad():` before validation could resolve? But I'll create another post for my second question after the 90 mins are up.

Comment: `So I have to reduce the number of epochs to 2` - I'd better decrease the learning rate and see if the error could go lower before interrupting training process

Comment: I understand that I use an  Adaptive Learning Rate with the Adam optimizer : `optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())`.
How should I decrease the learning rate ?

Comment: Set lr=1e-4 or lr=3e-4 in torch.optim.Adam https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.Adam.html